# Why do I get a 403 error?

Tags: 7

I'm trying to setup a REST server to allow login from external apps.
I managed to get the sequence working using the Poster plugin in Firefox but can't seem to replicate using a small Perl script.
I manage to get the X-CSRF-Token but fail to connect, getting a 403 response.

This is the sample Perl code.

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(env_proxy => 0,
keep_alive => 0,
timeout => 60);
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');

my $req = new HTTP::Request('GET', 'example.com/services/session/token');
my $response = $ua->request($req);
unless ($response->is_success) {
    die $response->status_line;
}
my $token = $response->content;

my $header= HTTP::Headers->new;
$header->header('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'X-CSRF-Token' => $token);

$req = new HTTP::Request('POST', 'example.com/smartphone_service/system/connect.xml', $header);
$response = $ua->request($req);
```

I installed the Services module and REST server locally, and that test worked. Service config is the same as the prod. What could be wrong?

Comment: `403 forbidden` says server forbid you access. To know why, you need to get corresponding message from server log. Add it to your question and we will be able to try to tell something. It may be Apache's mod_security or, well, many other things.

Comment: Have you tried posting to `http://mysite.com/smartphone_service/system/connect` instead of `http://mysite.com/smartphone_service/system/connect.xml` ?

Comment: There are no errors in apache logs. I've tried /smartphone_service/system/connect end even /smartphone_service, same result. I actually get a 404 but can see in drupal logs a page not found on 403.shtml. I've also tried renaming endpoint to "myendpoint".

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it. It was mod_security indeed. I could not see errors in my (cpanel) log because I am on a shared host but went ssh and saw it:

UNSUPPORTED DELAYED Rules: POST request must have a Content-Length header

```
$header->header('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Length' => 0, 'X-CSRF-Token' => $token);
```

That did the trick

Thank you Molot and David for taking the time to respond